# Trouble creating a dynamic row/columns for a grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a grid for wpf and I'm struggling a bit with how to best calculate the rows/columns for the grid. What I want to do is something along the lines of:

If I have 14 elements the grid will create 2 rows of 5 elements and 1 row of 4 elements.

If I pass in 12 it will give me 3 rows of 4 elements.

I have it working for a square shaped container but I want the container to be more rectangular for this part of the application. This code is below.

```
int count = (count of elements)
double squareRoot = Math.Sqrt(count);
int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling(squareRoot);
int columns = (int)Math.Floor(squareRoot);
```

The number of elements can be very dynamic so I need to come up with something that can handle a bunch of different options.  Also this is being built in C# so I can't use XAML suggestions.

Comment: Show us the code where you use `Grid.SetColumn` and `Grid.SetRow`.

Comment: it's a custom grid and I can't show that without sharing the whole class, I can tell you that currently if I have 4 items it gives me a grid with 2 rows and 2 columns. If I feed it 13 elements I get 5 rows and 4 columns(4 rows of 4, one row of one)

Comment: Your current method is almost certainly not the correct way to achieve your requirements. One method would be to use a number of basic `ItemsControl` elements and another would be to create your own custom `Panel` to use as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` in an `ItemsControl` element. I should also like to point out that it is a requirement of this website for you to show us what you have tried so far, as no one will just do your work for you. Please see the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the Help Centre.